# Change div's height and set absolute position break Bootstrap responsiveness

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Bootstrap 3.x** framework and **jQuery 2.x** library are been used.

I have four divs in three different rows. I am using jQuery to change the div height when mouse hover.

Use of z-index and absolute position break Bootstrap responsivness.

Using z-index and absolute position with .col-xs-* can provide a working solution. However, the result is not mobile friendly.

```js
$(function() {
  console.log(">>> jQuery is ready");
  $(".site-box-id-01").mouseenter(function() {
    console.log(">>> mouse enter");
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      height: "500px"
    }, {
      duration: 100
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    console.log(">>> mouse leave");
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
      height: "300px"
    }, {
      duration: 100
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.site-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
.row {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  height: 301px;
  /*      fix row height*/
}
.site-row-id-01 {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
.site-row-id-02 {
  background-color: azure;
}
.site-box-id-01 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="site-row-id-01">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-01">Test Box 01</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-01">Test Box 02</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-01">Test Box 03</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-class-02" id="site-row-id-02">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-02">Test Box 04</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-02">Test Box 05</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-02">Test Box 06</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

---

#### The Normal State

For Desktop

[image]

For Mobile

[image]

#### The Desired Result

For Desktop

[image]

For Mobile

[image]

#### The Current Result

For Desktop

[image]
(**NOT** Using **Absolute Positon** and **z-index** )

For Mobile

[image]
(Using **Absolute Positon** and **z-index**)

Comment: I am not going to add this as an answer because it does need a bit of refractoring. But maybe this will get you on your way https://jsfiddle.net/6taq7vcm/1/ . It is also using css for the animation, which is not ideal to your question. But i think something like this should be placed in the css . **Note** the row has a wrapper of relative which keeps it stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution at http://jsbin.com/fulequ/3/edit that I think meets your needs.

First, your html wasn't really responsive.  I modified it as below.  `class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"` gives 4 columns in desktop mode and 2 columns in mobile view.

```
   <div class="row" >
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-01">Test Box 01</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-01">Test Box 02</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" >
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-01">Test Box 03</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="site-box site-box-id-01">Test Box 04</div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

To expand a block vertically in desktop mode, add the following CSS class to the `<div class="site-box site-box-id-01">`and remove it on mouseleave() function.

```
.expand-box{
  z-index:1;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

For the mobile view you describe above, the JavaScript has to do the following

1. Set the height of the "row" div to the actual height that it is.
2. For each of the  position them absolutely to the position that they are currently at.
3. Add expand-box CSS class to div to enlarge.

On mouseleave, the JavaScript has to undo the above steps.