# Bootstrap: collapsed panels cause jumpy layout when exapanded

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I created a number of collapsed panel and put them in a bootstrap row to make their layout responsive.

When expanding panels however, the layout changes drastically, moving panels from one column to another.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L9nvvov/2/) shows my problem: upon expanding panel 1, panel 3 jumps from the first column to the second. Expanding panel 2 causes panel 3 to move downwards. Is there a way to fix this?

Here my current code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary description-item">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#id1">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                Panel 1
            </h4>

                </div>
                <div id="id1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">Some random text here that goes over 2 lines and maybe more</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary description-item">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#id2">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                Panel 2
            </h4>

                </div>
                <div id="id2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">Some random text here that goes over 2 lines and maybe more</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary description-item">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#id3">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                Panel 3
            </h4>

                </div>
                <div id="id3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">Some random text here that goes over 2 lines and maybe more</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary description-item">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#id4">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                Panel 4
            </h4>

                </div>
                <div id="id4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">Some random text here that goes over 2 lines and maybe more</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29331108/136717.  I think that is the answer to your question.

Comment: That is quite similar to what i was looking for, it will help! Thanks a lot!